# Fingerprint Sensor not showing on Ubuntu

Tags: 17.10, asus, fingerprint-reader

I have an Asus VivoBook 15(X510UAR) and I recently have installed Ubuntu 17.10 on it. I have a fingerprint sensor that works on Windows 10, but it doesn't work in Ubuntu.

Results of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Does it show up under lspci?

Comment: Does it show up with `lshw`?

Comment: No it does not show up in either.

Comment: Is there any update on this?

Comment: Can confirm, same laptop, same problem.

Comment: Is this a problem with the ELAN Touchpad thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097138/fingerprint-sensor-not-being-recognized-in-asus-s430ua

Comment: Same issue on my thinkpad T490