# Fingerprint sensor not being recognized in Asus S430UA

Tags: asus, fingerprint-reader

I recently purchased this laptop and installed Ubuntu 18.10 alongside Windows 10. It has a fingerprint sensor integrated with the touchpad. While it works fine with the Windows, it is not even recognized by the Ubuntu.

Here's the output for the `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56c1 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And here's the output for `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Comment: New Bug Report opended. Please vote for it https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1876502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the fingerprint sensor on the Asus notebooks is not yet supported in the libfprint library.  (It's the Elan Microelectronics reader)

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1641290 and please add your vote by clicking the "yes, it affects me too" indicator at the top of the bug report.  The more people show that they are affected, the greater the chance that this gets assigned to somebody to fix.

Because the hardware is not known, it doesn't even show in the lshw listing.

Answer (score 0):

I have ASUS VivoBook X510U. Fingerprint working fine in windows but not in ubuntu 18.04. Please, someone write the driver.